# DropDownlist returning first item always

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

aspx page has a UC. in aspx.cs

```
if(!isPostBack){
    UC.DataBind();
 }
```

this UC also has a usercontrol UC1. In UC.ascx.cs

```
 public void DataBind(){
   UC1.DataBind();
 }
```

in UC1

```
public void  DataBind(){
   List<Registeration> list = ... VAlues from database;
   dropdownlist1.DataSource = list;
   DropDownList1.DataTextField = 'username';
   DropDownList1.DataValueField = 'username';
   DropDownList1.databind();
}  

public void button1_click(){
    string selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
 }
```

**Problem : the value of string selectedValue is always coming out of the first item....**

Comments: DropDownList is in updatePanel

Answer (score 0):

Try populating the DropDownLost1.DataValueField in addition to the DataTextField.  Because it's not assigned, it might be empty for all items in the rendered DropDown.  To check this, you could look at the rendered HTML in FireBug to see what is showing up.

Comment: So the rendered HTML includes Text and Value for each ListItem?

Comment: The only other thing I could think is that UC.DataBind() or UC1.DataBind() are being called in another location.  Everything else looks okay to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are doing everything right, but you need to also add the `isPostBack()` on your usercontrol.